# INFORMS3 latex style, bibliography problem

Tags: natbib, templates, journal

I have a rather mysterious case. I follow the instructions on https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files
to set up a file, and here is my MWE. The problem is in bibliography.
In the standard cycle of `pdflatex mwe.tex`, then `bibtex mwe.aux` and then couple of `pdflatex`s after the *first* `pdflatex` command it *sometimes* shows that `citep{` is "undefined". At the end of the day, it does the right thing, though. You might ask what is the problem then. The problem is that I have a bigger file that is a "superset" of this MWE and both in Linux commandline (TeXLive) and Overleaf it shows this very error. After a few forceful `pdflatex`s it does compile, and produces the right thing. But I can just feel there is something wrong in the way I use bibliography here. I added `natbib` at the preamble, and also providing a sample `*.bib`-file for your reference. The `informs2014.bst` file can be found on the link above.
This is the first time I am using `natbib`. Just by looking at the MWEs below, what is wrong with the way components interact to mess up the bibliography in the way described?

```
\documentclass[mnsc]{informs3}
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXI
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     % Preferred (Theorem 1, Lemma 1, Theorem 2)
\ECRepeatTheorems
\EquationsNumberedThrough    % Default: (1), (2), ...
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[margin=1truein]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{framed}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\field}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\Pro}{\field{P}}
\newcommand{\Exp}{\field{E}}
\newcommand{\df}{\mathrm{d}}
\def\mb#1{\mbox{\mathbfmath $#1$}}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries} 
\newcommand{\beqna}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\eeqna}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\by}{\begin{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\ey}{\end{eqnarray*}}
\newcommand{\bn}{\begin{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\en}{\end{enumerate}}
\usepackage{mathtools,mathrsfs}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0.5mm}

\begin{document}

\ARTICLEAUTHORS{%
\AUTHOR{Snidely Slippery}
\AFF{Department of Bread Spread Engineering, Dairy University, Cowtown, IL 60208, \EMAIL{slippery@dairy.edu}} %, \URL{}}
\AUTHOR{Marg Arinella}
\AFF{Institute for Food Adulteration, University of Food Plains, Food Plains, MN 55599, \EMAIL{m.arinella@adult.ufp.edu}}
% Enter all authors
} % end of the block

\ABSTRACT{%
    abstract
}%

\KEYWORDS{keywords, more keywords} 

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\citep{RePEc:eee:jfinec:v:91:y:2009:i:3:p:278-287}

\newcommand{\newblock}{}
\bibliographystyle{informs2014}
\bibliography{mwe}
\end{document}
```

and bibliography:

```
@ARTICLE{RePEc:eee:jfinec:v:91:y:2009:i:3:p:278-287,
    title = {Strategic price complexity in retail financial markets},
    author = {Carlin, Bruce I.},
    year = {2009},
    journal = {Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume = {91},
    number = {3},
    pages = {278-287},
    abstract = {There is mounting empirical evidence to suggest that the law of one price is 
            violated in retail financial markets: there is significant price dispersion even when products are 
            homogeneous. Also, despite the large number of firms in the market, prices remain above marginal 
            cost and may even rise as more firms enter. In a non-cooperative oligopoly pricing model, I show that 
            these anomalies arise when firms add complexity to their price structures. Complexity increases the market power of the 
            firms because it prevents some consumers from becoming knowledgeable about prices in the market. In the model, 
            as competition increases, firms tend to add more complexity to their prices as a best response, rather 
            than make their disclosures more transparent. Because this may substantially decrease consumer 
            surplus in these markets, such practices have important welfare implications.},
    keywords = {Complexity Price dispersion Oligopoly},
    url = {https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:eee:jfinec:v:91:y:2009:i:3:p:278-287}
}
```

EDIT:
When running the full version of the paper through `pdflatex`, the very first run show this error message:
[image]
All this is followed by further errors:
[image]

Maybe the contents of the `final.bbl` (the where `final` is the actual paper the MWE is based on) can shed some light:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{15}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }

\bibitem[{Bellos et~al.(2017)Bellos, Ferguson, \protect\BIBand{}
  Toktay}]{doi:10.1287/msom.2016.0605}
Bellos I, Ferguson M, Toktay LB (2017) The car sharing economy: Interaction of
  business model choice and product line design. \emph{Manufacturing \& Service
  Operations Management} 19(2):185--201,
  \urlprefix\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/msom.2016.0605}.

\bibitem[{Benjaafar et~al.(2019)Benjaafar, Kong, Li, \protect\BIBand{}
  Courcoubetis}]{doi:10.1287/mnsc.2017.2970}
Benjaafar S, Kong G, Li X, Courcoubetis C (2019) Peer-to-peer product sharing:
  Implications for ownership, usage, and social welfare in the sharing economy.
  \emph{Management Science} 65(2):477--493,
  \urlprefix\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/mnsc.2017.2970}.

\bibitem[{Bimpikis et~al.(2019)Bimpikis, Candogan, \protect\BIBand{}
  Saban}]{doi:10.1287/opre.2018.1800}
Bimpikis K, Candogan O, Saban D (2019) Spatial pricing in ride-sharing
  networks. \emph{Operations Research} 67(3):744--769,
  \urlprefix\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1287/opre.2018.1800}.

\bibitem[{Boyd \protect\BIBand{} Vandenberghe(2004)}]{Boyd:2004:CO:993483}
Boyd S, Vandenberghe L (2004) \emph{Convex Optimization} (New York, NY, USA:
  Cambridge University Press), ISBN 0521833787.

\bibitem[{Carlin(2009)}]{RePEc:eee:jfinec:v:91:y:2009:i:3:p:278-287}
Carlin BI (2009) Strategic price complexity in retail financial markets.
  \emph{Journal of Financial Economics} 91(3):278--287,
  \urlprefix\url{https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:eee:jfinec:v:91:y:2009:i:3:p:278-287}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BibTeX style `informs2014.bst` uses `\BIBand` to separate authors, but the `informs3` class fails to define it.

The error only shows up if the bibliography includes multiauthor documents.

Add `\providecommand{\BIBand}{and}` (or `\&` instead of `and` if your research field has this usage) before `\begin{document}`.